# The character of a separable degree-$p$ extension of a local field of residual characteristic $p$ ?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number and $F$ a finite extension of ${\mathbf Q}_p$ or of ${\mathbf F}_p((t))$.  I'm going to define a natural map from the set ${\mathcal S}_p(F)$ of degree-$p$ separable extensions of $F$ into the group $F^\times/F^{\times p-1}$, and I want to know if this map has a name, or if you have come across it somewhere.

I need the auxillary field $K=F(\root{p-1}\of{F^\times})$, with group $G={\rm Gal}(K|F)$.  Note that ${\rm Hom}(G,{\mathbf F}_p^\times)$ is canonically isomorphic to $F^\times/F^{\times p-1}$. Note also that $K$ contains a primitive $p$-th root of $1$ if $F$ has characteristic $0$.

It can be shown that for every $E\in{\mathcal S}_p(F)$, the compositum $EK$ is cyclic of degree $p$ over $K$ and galoisian over $F$.   Therefore there is a $G$-stable ${\mathbf F}_p$-line $D\subset K^\times/K^{\times p}$ or $D\subset K^+/\wp(K^+)$, in characteristic $0$ and $p$ respectively, such that $EK=K(\root p\of D)$ or $EK=K(\wp^{-1}(D))$.  (Here $\wp$ is the endomorphism $x\mapsto x^p-x$ of the ${\mathbf F}_p$-space $K^+$ in characteristic $p$.)

Let $\chi:G\to{\mathbf F}_p^\times$ be the character through which $G$ acts on $D$. This assignment $E\mapsto\chi$ can be thought of as a map ${\mathcal S}_p(F)\to F^\times/F^{\times p-1}$.  I would like to know : Does this map manifest itself naturally in some context ?  Does it have a name ?

**Addendum** (2011/11/01)  The reason why I was interested in this map ${\mathcal S}_p(F)\to F^\times/F^{\times p-1}$ is that it partitions the set ${\mathcal S}_p(F)$ into $(p-1)^2=|F^\times/F^{\times p-1}|$ parts and one can compute the contribution of each of these parts to Serre's degree-$p$ mass formula.  This allows you to compute the contribution of cyclic extensions, or of those whose galoisian closure has a given group as group of automorphisms, or has ramification properties given in advance.  See [arXiv:1110.6702](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6702) for the details.

**Thanksgiving** (2011/11/30) I should have mentioned that the fact that *for every* $E\in{\mathcal S}_p(F)$, *the compositum* $EK$ *is cyclic of degree* $p$ *over* $K$ *and galoisian over* $F$ is a direct consequence of "Galois's Last Theorem" characterising solvable transitive subgroups of $\mathfrak{S}_p$ (see [Solvable transitive groups of prime degree](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24081/solvable-transitive-groups-of-prime-degree)).

Comment: In characteristic $p>0$, if you have an ordinary elliptic curve $\cal{E}$ over $F$ and a point $P \in \cal{E}(F)$ and you compute the field `$E_P$` obtained by dividing $P$ by Verschiebung, then the image of `$E_P$` under your map is the Hasse invariant of $\cal{E}$ and is thus independent of $P$. In this context, it arises naturally, but I don't have a general answer to your question.